# spriteBatch.Begin is getting a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, xna, nullreferenceexception, spritebatch, breakout

I'm relatively new and inexperienced to XNA and I've been following Jamie McMahon's guide to creating a basic Breakout game in C# (http://xnagpa.net/xna4beginner.php). Recently, I've stumbled across Microsoft's Game State Management code sample (http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management) and have been attempting to move my Breakout code over so I can make use of the menus the code sample offers me. However, whenever I try to launch the game, I get a NullReferenceException at spriteBatch.Begin in the following code:

```
#region File Description
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// GameplayScreen.cs
//
// Microsoft XNA Community Game Platform
// Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endregion

#region Using Statements
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using GameStateManagement;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
#endregion

namespace Rebound
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This screen implements the actual game logic. It is just a
    /// placeholder to get the idea across: you'll probably want to
    /// put some more interesting gameplay in here!
    /// </summary>
    public class GameplayScreen : GameScreen 
    {
        #region Fields

        ContentManager content;
        SpriteFont gameFont;
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        Ball ball;
        Paddle paddle;
        Rectangle screenRectangle;

        int bricksWide = 10;
        int bricksHigh = 5;
        Texture2D brickImage;
        Brick[,] bricks;

        float pauseAlpha;

        InputAction pauseAction;

        #endregion

        #region Initialization


        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor.
        /// </summary>

        public GameplayScreen()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 480;

            screenRectangle = new Rectangle(
                0,
                0,
                graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth,
                graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight);

            TransitionOnTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5);
            TransitionOffTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);

            pauseAction = new InputAction(
                new Buttons[] { Buttons.Start, Buttons.Back },
                new Keys[] { Keys.Escape },
                true);
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
            base.Initialize();  
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load graphics content for the game.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

                gameFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("gamefont");

                Texture2D tempTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("paddle");
                paddle = new Paddle(tempTexture, screenRectangle);

                tempTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ball");
                ball = new Ball(tempTexture, screenRectangle);

                brickImage = Content.Load<Texture2D>("brick");

                StartGame();

                // once the load has finished, we use ResetElapsedTime to tell the game's
                // timing mechanism that we have just finished a very long frame, and that
                // it should not try to catch up.
                ScreenManager.Game.ResetElapsedTime();
            base.LoadContent();
        }

        private void StartGame()
        {
            paddle.SetInStartPosition();
            ball.SetInStartPosition(paddle.GetBounds());

            bricks = new Brick[bricksWide, bricksHigh];

            for (int y = 0; y < bricksHigh; y++)
            {
                Color tint = Color.White;

                switch (y)
                {
                    case 0:
                        tint = Color.Blue;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tint = Color.Red;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        tint = Color.Green;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        tint = Color.Yellow;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        tint = Color.Purple;
                        break;
                }

                for (int x = 0; x < bricksWide; x++)
                {
                    bricks[x, y] = new Brick(
                        brickImage,
                        new Rectangle(
                            x * brickImage.Width,
                            y * brickImage.Height,
                            brickImage.Width,
                            brickImage.Height),
                        tint);
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>


        #endregion

        #region Update and Draw


        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the state of the game. This method checks the GameScreen.IsActive
        /// property, so the game will stop updating when the pause menu is active,
        /// or if you tab away to a different application.
        /// </summary>
        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime, bool otherScreenHasFocus,
                                                       bool coveredByOtherScreen)
        {
            base.Update(gameTime, otherScreenHasFocus, false);

            // Gradually fade in or out depending on whether we are covered by the pause screen.
            if (coveredByOtherScreen)
                pauseAlpha = Math.Min(pauseAlpha + 1f / 32, 1);
            else
                pauseAlpha = Math.Max(pauseAlpha - 1f / 32, 0);

            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)

                this.Exit(); 

            paddle.Update();
            ball.Update();

            foreach (Brick brick in bricks)
            {
                brick.CheckCollision(ball);
            }

            ball.PaddleCollision(paddle.GetBounds());

            if (ball.OffBottom())
                StartGame();

            base.Update(gameTime, otherScreenHasFocus, coveredByOtherScreen);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Draws the gameplay screen.
        /// </summary>
        public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // This game has a blue background. Why? Because!
            ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.Target,
                                               Color.CornflowerBlue, 0, 0);
            spriteBatch.Begin();

            foreach (Brick brick in bricks)
                brick.Draw(spriteBatch);

            paddle.Draw(spriteBatch);
            ball.Draw(spriteBatch);

            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);

            // If the game is transitioning on or off, fade it out to black.
            if (TransitionPosition > 0 || pauseAlpha > 0)
            {
                float alpha = MathHelper.Lerp(1f - TransitionAlpha, 1f, pauseAlpha / 2);

                ScreenManager.FadeBackBufferToBlack(alpha);
            }
        }


        #endregion
    }
}
```

So where am I going wrong here? I've done a bit of research on this error and none of the solutions have helped me out. Feel free to point out any other redundancies / mistakes in my code because I am extremely inexperienced with this sort of thing. Thanks!

Edit: Adding original GameplayScreen.cs from Microsoft's GameStateManagement code sample and the Breakout game code I am trying to merge with it. If anyone knows an easy way to do so, I would love to hear their advice.

Breakout game code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Rebound
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        Ball ball;
        Paddle paddle;
        Rectangle screenRectangle;

        int bricksWide = 10;
        int bricksHigh = 5;
        Texture2D brickImage;
        Brick[,] bricks;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 750;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;

            screenRectangle = new Rectangle(
                0,
                0,
                graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth,
                graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            Texture2D tempTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("paddle");
            paddle = new Paddle(tempTexture, screenRectangle);

            tempTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ball");
            ball = new Ball(tempTexture, screenRectangle);

            brickImage = Content.Load<Texture2D>("brick");

            StartGame();
        }

        private void StartGame()
        {
            paddle.SetInStartPosition();
            ball.SetInStartPosition(paddle.GetBounds());

            bricks = new Brick[bricksWide, bricksHigh];

            for (int y = 0; y < bricksHigh; y++)
            {
                Color tint = Color.White;

                switch (y)
                {
                    case 0:
                        tint = Color.Blue;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tint = Color.Red;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        tint = Color.Green;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        tint = Color.Yellow;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        tint = Color.Purple;
                        break;
                }

                for (int x = 0; x < bricksWide; x++)
                {
                    bricks[x, y] = new Brick(
                        brickImage,
                        new Rectangle(
                            x * brickImage.Width,
                            y * brickImage.Height,
                            brickImage.Width,
                            brickImage.Height),
                        tint);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            paddle.Update();
            ball.Update();

            foreach (Brick brick in bricks)
            {
                brick.CheckCollision(ball);
            }

            ball.PaddleCollision(paddle.GetBounds());

            if (ball.OffBottom())
                StartGame();

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            spriteBatch.Begin();

            foreach (Brick brick in bricks)
                brick.Draw(spriteBatch);

            paddle.Draw(spriteBatch);
            ball.Draw(spriteBatch);

            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Original GameplayScreen.cs from Microsoft code sample:

```
#region File Description
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// GameplayScreen.cs
//
// Microsoft XNA Community Game Platform
// Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endregion

#region Using Statements
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using GameStateManagement;
#endregion

namespace GameStateManagementSample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This screen implements the actual game logic. It is just a
    /// placeholder to get the idea across: you'll probably want to
    /// put some more interesting gameplay in here!
    /// </summary>
    class GameplayScreen : GameScreen
    {
        #region Fields

        ContentManager content;
        SpriteFont gameFont;

        Vector2 playerPosition = new Vector2(100, 100);
        Vector2 enemyPosition = new Vector2(100, 100);

        Random random = new Random();

        float pauseAlpha;

        InputAction pauseAction;

        #endregion

        #region Initialization


        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor.
        /// </summary>
        public GameplayScreen()
        {
            TransitionOnTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5);
            TransitionOffTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);

            pauseAction = new InputAction(
                new Buttons[] { Buttons.Start, Buttons.Back },
                new Keys[] { Keys.Escape },
                true);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Load graphics content for the game.
        /// </summary>
        public override void Activate(bool instancePreserved)
        {
            if (!instancePreserved)
            {
                if (content == null)
                    content = new ContentManager(ScreenManager.Game.Services, "Content");

                gameFont = content.Load<SpriteFont>("gamefont");

                // A real game would probably have more content than this sample, so
                // it would take longer to load. We simulate that by delaying for a
                // while, giving you a chance to admire the beautiful loading screen.
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                // once the load has finished, we use ResetElapsedTime to tell the game's
                // timing mechanism that we have just finished a very long frame, and that
                // it should not try to catch up.
                ScreenManager.Game.ResetElapsedTime();
            }

#if WINDOWS_PHONE
            if (Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey("PlayerPosition"))
            {
                playerPosition = (Vector2)Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["PlayerPosition"];
                enemyPosition = (Vector2)Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["EnemyPosition"];
            }
#endif
        }


        public override void Deactivate()
        {
#if WINDOWS_PHONE
            Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["PlayerPosition"] = playerPosition;
            Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["EnemyPosition"] = enemyPosition;
#endif

            base.Deactivate();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Unload graphics content used by the game.
        /// </summary>
        public override void Unload()
        {
            content.Unload();

#if WINDOWS_PHONE
            Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Remove("PlayerPosition");
            Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Remove("EnemyPosition");
#endif
        }


        #endregion

        #region Update and Draw


        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the state of the game. This method checks the GameScreen.IsActive
        /// property, so the game will stop updating when the pause menu is active,
        /// or if you tab away to a different application.
        /// </summary>
        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime, bool otherScreenHasFocus,
                                                       bool coveredByOtherScreen)
        {
            base.Update(gameTime, otherScreenHasFocus, false);

            // Gradually fade in or out depending on whether we are covered by the pause screen.
            if (coveredByOtherScreen)
                pauseAlpha = Math.Min(pauseAlpha + 1f / 32, 1);
            else
                pauseAlpha = Math.Max(pauseAlpha - 1f / 32, 0);

            if (IsActive)
            {
                // Apply some random jitter to make the enemy move around.
                const float randomization = 10;

                enemyPosition.X += (float)(random.NextDouble() - 0.5) * randomization;
                enemyPosition.Y += (float)(random.NextDouble() - 0.5) * randomization;

                // Apply a stabilizing force to stop the enemy moving off the screen.
                Vector2 targetPosition = new Vector2(
                    ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2 - gameFont.MeasureString("Insert Gameplay Here").X / 2, 
                    200);

                enemyPosition = Vector2.Lerp(enemyPosition, targetPosition, 0.05f);

                // TODO: this game isn't very fun! You could probably improve
                // it by inserting something more interesting in this space :-)
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Lets the game respond to player input. Unlike the Update method,
        /// this will only be called when the gameplay screen is active.
        /// </summary>
        public override void HandleInput(GameTime gameTime, InputState input)
        {
            if (input == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("input");

            // Look up inputs for the active player profile.
            int playerIndex = (int)ControllingPlayer.Value;

            KeyboardState keyboardState = input.CurrentKeyboardStates[playerIndex];
            GamePadState gamePadState = input.CurrentGamePadStates[playerIndex];

            // The game pauses either if the user presses the pause button, or if
            // they unplug the active gamepad. This requires us to keep track of
            // whether a gamepad was ever plugged in, because we don't want to pause
            // on PC if they are playing with a keyboard and have no gamepad at all!
            bool gamePadDisconnected = !gamePadState.IsConnected &&
                                       input.GamePadWasConnected[playerIndex];

            PlayerIndex player;
            if (pauseAction.Evaluate(input, ControllingPlayer, out player) || gamePadDisconnected)
            {
#if WINDOWS_PHONE
                ScreenManager.AddScreen(new PhonePauseScreen(), ControllingPlayer);
#else
                ScreenManager.AddScreen(new PauseMenuScreen(), ControllingPlayer);
#endif
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise move the player position.
                Vector2 movement = Vector2.Zero;

                if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
                    movement.X--;

                if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
                    movement.X++;

                if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
                    movement.Y--;

                if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                    movement.Y++;

                Vector2 thumbstick = gamePadState.ThumbSticks.Left;

                movement.X += thumbstick.X;
                movement.Y -= thumbstick.Y;

                if (input.TouchState.Count > 0)
                {
                    Vector2 touchPosition = input.TouchState[0].Position;
                    Vector2 direction = touchPosition - playerPosition;
                    direction.Normalize();
                    movement += direction;
                }

                if (movement.Length() > 1)
                    movement.Normalize();

                playerPosition += movement * 8f;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Draws the gameplay screen.
        /// </summary>
        public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // This game has a blue background. Why? Because!
            ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.Target,
                                               Color.CornflowerBlue, 0, 0);

            // Our player and enemy are both actually just text strings.
            SpriteBatch spriteBatch = ScreenManager.SpriteBatch;

            spriteBatch.Begin();

            spriteBatch.DrawString(gameFont, "// TODO", playerPosition, Color.Green);

            spriteBatch.DrawString(gameFont, "Insert Gameplay Here",
                                   enemyPosition, Color.DarkRed);

            spriteBatch.End();

            // If the game is transitioning on or off, fade it out to black.
            if (TransitionPosition > 0 || pauseAlpha > 0)
            {
                float alpha = MathHelper.Lerp(1f - TransitionAlpha, 1f, pauseAlpha / 2);

                ScreenManager.FadeBackBufferToBlack(alpha);
            }
        }


        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I'm fairly certain that I have initialised the spriteBatch though, and I have absolutely no idea how it is coming up as null.

Comment: Oh, I wonder if you are breaking the _Microsoft Permissive License (Ms-PL)_ by showing that code above?

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing `spriteBatch` in `LoadContent`. Are you sure you are running `GamePlayScreen.Loadcontent()` before you are doing anything with it? Maybe you could show us the Class where you use this `GameScreen` Object. On the otherhand, you could just use the `SpriteBatch` object from the main class by passing it to the draw method of `GameScreen`.

```
public void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spritebatch)
{
}

//In the main class (Game1) you can use draw like this:

gameScreen.Draw(gameTime, spritebatch);
```

Also, i never used GameTime in my draw method.  GameTime afaik is used for updating logic, in the Update method. I have the feeling you are creating a bit of a mess. Just start over, maybe a more simple tutorial to start with. The gameScreen requires basic knowledge of inheritance. When you want to know more about gamescreen management i advice to learn some more about inheritance first.

Comment: By GameScreen do you mean GameplayScreen?Also, the Breakout tutorial says to add GameTime to the Draw method. 

I have been able to create a successful Breakout game by following the tutorial, and I am trying to merge the game code with Microsoft's code sample for Game State Management so I can have nice menus. I will update the OP with the original Breakout game's code and the original GameplayScreen.cs from the Microsoft code sample. I really just need to merge the two so if you know a smoother way to do so I would much appreciate it if you could help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

You dont seem to have an activate method in your code (unless i just missed it).
From memory this is the method that is actually called from the screen manager. Overwrite this method, and call your loadcontent method from there.
Additionally - you shouldn't need to recreate your spritebatch. Im fairly sure the screen manager has a reference to it - so instead you should have something along the lines of this.spritebatch = ScreenManager.Spritebatch;

Again - this is from memory, I can update this again later once im home and can reference my own project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the texture files first? Because if not then that is why it gives a null exception...because it can not find and load texture files.